# Borrar un archivo Java

Tags: java

B tardes!
Estoy intentando borrar un archivo de una carpeta mediante un menú en el que el usuario elija el archivo a borrar.
En el ejemplo que pongo a continuación, lo he simplificado para ralizar la pregunta, y he creado un array tipo String, cuando en realidad se trata de una carpeta con archivos reales .txt

```
public class pruebas04 {

static InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //@FranBarcos

    String archivos [] = {"archivo1","archivo2","archivo3", "archivo4"};
    int num=pideEntero("Indique el Nº de Archivo a Borrar: ");
    num--;


    File borrado = new File (archivos[num]);
    borrado.delete();
    System.out.print("El archivo seleccionado es: "+borrado+"\n");
    System.out.print("El Archivo "+borrado+" se ha Eliminado con Éxito!!.\n");

    for(int i=0; i<archivos.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(archivos[i]);
    }//end for


}//end main

static public int pideEntero(String text) throws Exception{
    int num=0;
    boolean correcto;

    do {correcto=true;
        try {
            System.out.print(text);
            num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }//end try
        catch(Exception er) {
            System.out.print("ERROR!, ");
            correcto=false;
        }//end catch
    }while(!correcto);
    return num;
}//end pideEntero

}//end class
```

Lo que me parece raro, es que si imprimo por consola el File "borrado", me devuelve el archivo correcto, es decir, el seleccionado por el "usuario" para borrar, sin embargo, NO borra nada y cuando compruebo el contenido de la carpeta, ahí sigue el archivo que se debió borrar y NO sé por qué.
Alguien puede aportar una explicación a este novato que os escribe?
y una solución, claro!

Comment: eclipse, Pero  ya he dado con la solución. Dde la forma que lo tengo se accede a la información, pero NO al archivo, para acceder al archivo hay que poner la ruta. he modificado esto: File borrado = new File (rutaCompleta+archivos[num]); y ya está solventado.

Comment: @franb70 de todos debes tener en cuenta que el método `File.delete()` devuelve un `boolean` que indica si el archivo o directorio pudo borrarse ya que puede sarse el caso de que otro proceso tenga bloqueado el archivo y no puedas borrarlo.

Comment: Gracias!! pero no era eso, era lo que he expuesto antes. Ya está solventado. Muchas Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: si lo sé, vi tu comentario, solo te hago el apunte porque es importante.